# How to get a $_POST request from view module?

Tags: php, html, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to get the checkboxes from a table in a view module, but I can't get it to work. This is the table:

```
     <form action="" method="post">
     <TABLE id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
        <THEAD>
          <TR>
            <TH></TH>
            <TH>ID</TH>
            <TH>Client</TH>
            <TH>User</TH>
            <TH>Role</TH>
            <TH>Projects</TH>
          </TR>
        </THEAD>
        <TBODY>
<?php
/* @var $item Admin\Model\User */
foreach ($this->users as $item) {
    ?>
    <TR>
        <TD class='admin'><input type="checkbox" name="users[<?php echo $item->id; ?>]" value=<?php echo $item->id; ?> checked/></TD>
        <TD class='admin c'><?= $item->id ?></TD>
        <TD class='admin'><?= $item->getClientObject() ?></TD>
        <TD class='admin'>
            <img src="<?= $item->getAvatarPath() ?>" alt="me" class="online avatar"/>
            <a title='details'
               href='/admin/user/detail/id/<?= $item->id ?>'><?= $item->name . " " . $item->surname ?> </a>
        </TD>
        <TD class='admin'><?= $item->getRoleObject() ?></TD>
        <TD class='admin'>
            <a title='projects' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'
               href='/admin/user/project/id/<?= $item->id ?>'><i
                    class='fa fa-icon-fix fa-briefcase'></i></a>
            <?
            foreach ($this->projects[$item->id] as $i => $project) {
                echo $project->getName();
                if ($i != sizeof($this->projects[$item->id]) - 1)
                    echo " • ";
            }
            ?>
        </TD>
    </TR>
<?php
}
?>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
    </form>
```

The whole `.phtml` : http://pastebin.com/8paJZgjb

I want to get the `users[]` array and use its elements inside the controller, but I can't find a way to get it. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
           if (!empty($_POST["users"])) {
            foreach (($_POST["users"]) as $selectedUsers) {
                $users = $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll(false, "id=" .  $selectedUsers);
            }
        } else {
            $this->cache->error = "Please choose at least one user.";
            return $this->view;
        }
```

The whole function: http://pastebin.com/pE4afemx

...but apparently it's empty.
`var_dump` shows the elements from the mailing form, but no sign of the users:

```
array (size=2)
'subject' => string 'hello' (length=5)
'message' => string 'message' (length=7)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should use `$this->getRequest()->getPost('users');` or if you're using a zend form you use `$form->getValue('users');`. $_POST should work though... did you try simple debugging like `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: I did what you said and it doesn't say it's empty now, however it doesn't show them as $_POSTS either, weird. Is it because I didn't put the controller as an action for the form ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you get for `var_dump($_POST);exit;` from your controller after submitting the form. The blank action is not the issue.

Comment: @TimFountain I did what you asked

Comment: Okay, it might help if you could edit your question to include the whole form, as the problem isn't in the code you've posted. The form in your question has no 'subject' or 'message' fields, yet they're all you're getting.

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks for your time! Posted them above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in your pastebin link, you have *two* forms on the page. One starts on line 16, contains your user checkboxes, and then ends on line 61. Then the second starts on line 77 and ends on line 79. I'm guessing this the one being submitted by the javascript submit button you have on line 86.

Since you're submitting the second form, only its data gets posted. If you want everything to be submitted, it all needs to be in one form. Ideally you'd move the user checkboxes out of this template they're output as part of `$form`, but it might be tricky to keep them in a table layout that way, so the easier fix would be to move the table that contains the user checkboxes so it is output after the `echo $this->formCollection($form);`, but before that form ends with `echo $this->form()->closeTag();`. Get rid of the form tags you have on line 16 and 61, since you only want one form.

**Edit**: To fix the other issue, try changing your controller code to this:

```
if (!empty($_POST["users"])) {
    $userIDs = array();
    foreach ($_POST["users"] as $selectedUser) {
        if (is_numeric($selectedUser) && $selectedUser > 0) {
            $userIDs[] = $selectedUser;
        }
    }

    if (count($userIDs) > 0) {
        $users = $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll(false, "id IN (".implode(', ', $userIDs).")");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! But now it only send the message to the last person selected...

Comment: Your controller code loops through the submitted users and for each one loads it from the DB and stores it in `$users`. So each iteration will overwrite the previous user. Can you add the code for your fetchAll() function to your question?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. This isn't really the "right" way, really your `fetchAll()` function needs modification but it should work as a quick fix.

Comment: It works flawlessly now, thank you for everything! Godspeed! :)